# Upload large files Spring Webflux

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I want to upload files to a minio file container.
Smaller files work as expected with this code:

```
private Mono<Boolean> saveFileToMinio(FilePart filePart) {
    log.info("About to save database to minio container...");
    Mono<Boolean> result = Mono.from(
            filePart.content().flatMap(dataBuffer -> {
                        var bytes = dataBuffer.asByteBuffer().array();
                        dataBuffer.read(bytes);
                        DataBufferUtils.release(dataBuffer);
                        return Flux.just(bytes);
                    })
                    .flatMap(databaseFileService::write)
                    .then(Mono.just(true))
                    .onErrorMap(throwable -> {
                        log.error(throwable.getMessage(), throwable);
                        return throwable;
                    }));
    log.info("Successfully saved database to minio container...");
    return result;
}
```

I need to provide a `byte[]` for my minio service to be uploaded.
Smaller files work as expected (will be stored to the container). But larger files (12 MB in my test) don´t work.

I get this exception:
`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: readPosition 0 and length 1024 should be smaller than writePosition 808`

Answer (score 3):

I´ve tried a suggestion `DataBufferUtils.join` from another SO post. This is kind of odd but i think the following code does the job:

```
private Mono<Boolean> saveFileToMinio(FilePart filePart) {

    var result = DataBufferUtils.join(filePart.content()).map(dataBuffer -> {
                var bytes = dataBuffer.asByteBuffer().array();
                dataBuffer.read(bytes);
                DataBufferUtils.release(dataBuffer);
                return bytes;
            }).map(databaseFileService::write).then(Mono.just(true))
            .onErrorMap(throwable -> {
                log.error(throwable.getMessage(), throwable);
                return throwable;
            });
    log.info("Successfully saved database to minio container...");
    return result;
}
```

Especially this line seems to do the trick:
`DataBufferUtils.join`

I don´t know why but it seems to work.

**EDIT:**
Looking up the above static `join` sets a parameter `maxByteCount` to `-1`. Maybe the other (not working function for larger files) sets some limits. But i don´t know.

Comment: Thanks man, this comment saved me hours

Comment: Sorry, but i think ```DataBufferUtils.join``` won't work on file, whose size is bigger than Integer.MAX_VALUE: there're internal byte[] for joining file parts.